# I have an array that is generated on page, saved as an variable. How to to send it with a POST to db (mongodb, node, express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post

A node, express, mongodb question.

I have a webpage, with a some JS-code. The user types some things into the my form and then they can generate a table with data. Before the table is printed to the user the data as saved as a variable (Array). The array itself is named obj.invoices.

I can easily save the data from the form to the DB using the "name". When I use it shows up in the req.body, which i then can use in my controller and save it to the DB.

But how do i pass the generated variable (obj.invoices) from the page so that it will follow along in the POST and shows up in the req.body?

As for now the array isn't parsed so i cant build a function in express/mongoose to save the data to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it but I'm quite sure this is a bad solution.

When finished generating the array I run this function,

```
function showArray() {

var json_data = JSON.stringify(myArray);
document.getElementById('showArray').innerHTML = json_data;

}
```

This convert the array to string, and then post it into a input within my form;

```
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea id="showArray" class="textarea is-info" type="text"  name="ArrayToDb"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So when i submit my form the array as a string is posted with the req.body. Then in my controller.js for the app I convert the string back to an array;

```
let jsonArray = JSON.parse(req.body.ArrayToDb)
```

and then i save it to the DB

```
    newLan.fakturor = jsonArray;

    newLan.save(function (err) {
        console.log(newLan._id)
    });
```

Like I said, this is most likely a really bad way to do it but it works for me, for now.